# Jquery ui accordion - how to add an icon to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

whats the css/added html to add one of the jquery ui icons to the right side of the accordation widget's headers?

for example, if i have the html:

```
    <!-- Accordion -->
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#"><span class="title">Content</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span></a></h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
            <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
            <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

can i add css to make the jquery ui icon appear on the right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think i've figured this out. By adding this css it seems to work fine.

```
#accordion a span.title {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#accordion a span.ui-icon {
    position: static;   
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Let me know if any issues are found with this.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? (be sure to change "redmond" theme to fit your theme)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });    
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body { font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px; }
    ul.icons { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    ul.icons li { margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 2px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left; list-style: none;}
    ul.icons span.ui-icon { float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
    .acc-content { position:relative; }
    .icon-group { position:absolute; top:0px; right:2px; z-index:9999; cursor:pointer;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="acc-content">
        <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <ul class="icons icon-group ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
            <li title="Complete"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span></li>
            <li title="Help" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="acc-content">
        <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
        <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="acc-content">
        <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    /*right: 0.75em !important;*/
    left: 585px;
}
```

As mentioned earlier in this post, setting the absolute positioning to 'right: x;' doesn't do the job (inexplicably). So I just gave it a very large 'left' value. Feels a wee bit hacky but so be it.

Comment: Make sure you have "position:absolute;" set:

    `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0.5em;
      top: 0.5em;
     }`

Comment: I've used this to get the Accordion up/down chevrons over to the r-h side:
`.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
 position: absolute;
 left: 95%;
 top: 53%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`float:right` for `ui-icon` should do the trick. Eventually, add `float:left` to `span.title` to avoid any IE issues.

Comment: it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: the ui-icon span is absolutely positioned making this useless. Instead, change left: .5em in the ui-icon declaration to right: .5em

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#accordion h3 a {width:100%}
#accordion h3 a .ui-icon {float:right}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks *Sevmusic*. This is a follow-up on your post for those who want to have nested accordions and still have an icon-group above each one of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".x").accordion({
            header: "h3",
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            autoHeight: false
        });

        $(".xy").accordion({
            header: "h4",
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            autoHeight: false
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    ul.icons
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul.icons li
    {
        margin: 2px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 2px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul.icons span.ui-icon
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 4px;
    }
    .accordionContent
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    .icon-group
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 2px;
        z-index: 9999;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<div class="x">
    <div class="accordionContent">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">First Outer</a></h3>
        <div>
            <div class="xy" style="position: relative;">
                <h4>
                    <a href="#">Second Inner</a></h4>
                <div>
                    Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
                <ul class="icons icon-group ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
                    <li title="Complete"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></li>
                    <li title="Help" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help">
                    </span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="icons icon-group ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
            <li title="Complete"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span></li>
            <li title="Help" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help">
            </span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully, this would save someone a bit of time getting this to work!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why you solve too hard. Easy solution for icons and switch off padding of title in H3 tag. Set this to your css loaded after jquery styles.

```js
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(function () {
        var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
            activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
        };
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            icons: icons,
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="width: 90%; margin: 3% auto 5% auto;">
    <div id="accordion" style="border: 0;">
        <h3>
            <span class="width-fix"># 1</span><span>Test 00</span>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Nam malesuada egestas magna, et suscipit magna auctor quis. Donec rhoncus elementum sapien, vel euismod ex aliquam ultrices. Maecenas aliquet at ligula consectetur lobortis. Ut eget turpis sem. Etiam blandit, tortor vel congue vulputate, elit velit volutpat ipsum, sit amet elementum dui augue vel ante. Donec vel placerat risus, nec dapibus dolor. Curabitur molestie justo quis est rhoncus tincidunt. Integer posuere mauris et eros efficitur, sed finibus nunc blandit. In convallis arcu ac mi ornare viverra.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>
            <span class="black width-fix"># 2</span><span>Test 01</span>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin, erat a ultricies molestie, orci lectus faucibus metus, a luctus est ipsum non odio. Duis cursus fermentum nunc, et pellentesque lorem tristique et. Donec bibendum lacus in mi feugiat ornare. Etiam a scelerisque est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam in enim at erat ornare posuere a id eros. Donec id tempus turpis. Integer scelerisque turpis ut finibus fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent molestie elit lacus, a pellentesque nisi pulvinar eget. Nulla cursus aliquet eros a dapibus. Aliquam vitae purus sed mi accumsan molestie pretium vel arcu. Integer tempor ut magna in porttitor. Nulla facilisi.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>
            <span class="black width-fix"># 3</span><span class="orange">Test 02</span>
        </h3>
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin, erat a ultricies molestie, orci lectus faucibus metus, a luctus est ipsum non odio. Duis cursus fermentum nunc, et pellentesque lorem tristique et. Donec bibendum lacus in mi feugiat ornare. Etiam a scelerisque est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam in enim at erat ornare posuere a id eros. Donec id tempus turpis. Integer scelerisque turpis ut finibus fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent molestie elit lacus, a pellentesque nisi pulvinar eget. Nulla cursus aliquet eros a dapibus. Aliquam vitae purus sed mi accumsan molestie pretium vel arcu. Integer tempor ut magna in porttitor. Nulla facilisi.
            </p>
        </div>
        <h3>
            <span class="black width-fix"># 4</span><span class="orange">Test 03</span>
        </h3>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sollicitudin, erat a ultricies molestie, orci lectus faucibus metus, a luctus est ipsum non odio. Duis cursus fermentum nunc, et pellentesque lorem tristique et. Donec bibendum lacus in mi feugiat ornare. Etiam a scelerisque est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam in enim at erat ornare posuere a id eros. Donec id tempus turpis. Integer scelerisque turpis ut finibus fermentum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent molestie elit lacus, a pellentesque nisi pulvinar eget. Nulla cursus aliquet eros a dapibus. Aliquam vitae purus sed mi accumsan molestie pretium vel arcu. Integer tempor ut magna in porttitor. Nulla facilisi.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
  .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {
    padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: unset;
    top: 50%;
    right: .5em;
}
.width-fix {
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

  </style>
```