# jquery accordion heading and div widths do not match after adding an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

after adding 2 additional icons (edit, delete) to the heading, the heading and div widths no longer match.  How can I get the widths for the heading and div to match just like a standard accordion?  Thanks

```
<div id="accordion">
                          <h3><a href="javascript:;">
                          <span style="float:right;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil hand" onclick="javascript:doEdit();"></span>
                          <span style="float:right;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash hand" onclick="javascript:doDelete();"></span>
                          <span>Created By: J Doe</span>
                            </a>
                            </h3>
                          <div>
                            <p>test</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
#accordion a span.ui-icon {
    position: static;   
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
}
```

found it from this post:
[Jquery ui accordion - how to add an icon to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477062/jquery-ui-accordion-how-to-add-an-icon-to-the-right)